# How do I cut and paste terminal I/O without using the mouse?

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, search

I want to search and cut text from command output in a terminal so I can use it in subsequent command line invocations or just in an editor session.

Is there any way to easily run a regular expression against the output of a terminal and  cutting results without touching the mouse?

My requirements are:

- it should work while working with remote machines through ssh. In those machines I can not install extra software there so the solution must be local.
- if possible, it must be "always present". For instance, if I'm running a long process and suddenly it fails I'd like to be able to grep through the output without having to start the process again with a prepared environment.

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer to your question (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[screen(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/screen.1.html) allows you to copy/paste using the keyboard, but it requires that you run your shell/process inside `screen`.

To copy, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd>, move the cursor (using the arrow keys) to the start point and hit <kbd>⏎</kbd> (RETURN), move the cursor to the end point and hit <kbd>⏎</kbd>. The marked text is now copied.

To paste, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd>

This solution also applies to Byobu, since Byobu is just a wrapper around screen.

Answer (score 5):

### *xclip* and *grep* and pipes!

- Install the `xclip` utility (`sudo apt-get install xclip`)

  - By default, `xclip` is set to copy piped input to the clipboard
  - `xclip -o` will "paste" the contents of the clipboard into your terminal (i.e. standard output)
- For regular expressions, just pipe the command to grep; the `-P` switch will give you full Perl regex functionality.
- Example: `ls -lR | grep -P "anc.*" | xclip` to copy to clipboard

  - Use `tee xclip` instead so that it gets displayed AND copied.

Comment: I didn't know about xclip and it seems useful but it doesn't solve my current problem. See the updated question.

Comment: @ancechu: Well, that's why you should explain as much of the context as possible in the question to start with. Do you ssh from Windows, if so which program? Or just from gnome-terminal, etc.?

Comment: I'm working from a Linux machine, mainly using terminator and ssh-ing to remote boxes